# trying to connect to machine using putty

Tags: putty, connection

I try to login using PuTTY using the below:

```
putty.exe username@ipaddress -pw password -m commands.txt
```

I get the below error:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2016.06.07 01:26:30 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "username".
Invalid call with 3 args: 'chrootsh' '-c' 'date'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an error from the server you're connecting to. Do you have control over that machine? This cannot be fixed from the client-side.

Comment: yes,when i using the same command without script it is executing but by this it doesnt work

Comment: The server doesn't support that due to a bug in its chroot setup; which you should report to the admin of that server

Comment: is there any other way to connect using putty?